# homotopy invariance homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to understand the proof of theorem 2.10 in Hatcher (Homotopic invariance). He starts out by the construction of the prism operator and defines a linear map $\phi:\Delta^n \rightarrow I$ defined in barycentric coordinates by $\phi_i(t_0,...,t_n)=t_{i+1}+\cdot \cdot \cdot + t_{n}$ and claims that the n-simplex $[v_0,...,v_i,w_{i+1},...,w_n]$ is the graph of this map.

I am sure that I am missing something obvious, but I cannot figure out how a n-simplex can be the graph of a function that sends out a number between 0 and 1. How can a number be a graph?

Comment: No definition of the graph of a function of which I am aware would lead anyone to the conclusion that a number is a graph.

Comment: I agree.. So what does Hatcher mean by the graph of the map $\phi$?

Comment: The same as everyone means: the set of ordered tuples $(t_0,...,t_n,y)$ such that $\phi(t_0,...,t_n)=y$.

Comment: I guess I was right about missing something obvious:) Thanks